# Android browser displays border wrongly around image with border radius

Tags: android, html, css, border

I'm having some problems with displaying a border around an image correctly. In all browsers, but one, the image tested correctly. The browser that displays problems is my stock browser on my own HTC One (Android KitKat 4.4).

**Edit:** It works perfectly on the stock browser of the Galaxy S4.

The **problem** in this browser is that the border is only shown on four points (top, right, bottom, left) and the rest of the border is covered by the image itself. A picture says more than a thousand words so I included two screenshots in the links below.

**Basic markup of image:**

```
border-radius: 50%;
border: 1px solid #818d94;
```

**Images:**

[Stock Android browser (HTC One)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNUXB.jpg)

[Chrome on Android (HTC One)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjQJA.jpg)

Thank you for your time

Comment: browsers all render differently. The stock browser on Android is the least capable.  I've read that rather than trying to make rounded corners show up on that browser, bit the bullet and use images. Sucks, but the hybrid thing just isn't up to the task all the time

Comment: Thank you for your response Martin. I've build the whole frontend for a pretty big project (http://www.jobado.nl) and this is a user driven platform. Cross browser testing is one of my least favorite things. I could use transparent overlays, but there are different backgrounds, etc. If I had to make a choice between ignoring the rendering on the stock Android browser of my HTC One or implementing images at this point, I'll go with ignoring this problem. I'm trying to be a pixel perfect developer and this small thing is driving me crazy.